# How to sum absolute values from columns in dplyr?

Tags: r, sum, dplyr, absolute-value

I have this dataset with two columns and four rows

```
x <- c(-1, -2, 2, 3)
y <- c(0, -3, 2, -2)

cbind(x, y)
```

I want to sum the absolute values of columns `x` and `y` using `dplyr` and add results in column `z`. It should look like this

```
z <- c(1, 5, 4, 5)

cbind(x, y, z)
```

I have tried using `mutate` and place the argument `abs` in different positions of a command but nothing works.

Can anyone help this R beginner solve this apparent simple problem?

Thanks,

Comment: `data.frame(x,y) %>% mutate(z = abs(x) + abs(y))`

Comment: The base R version - `dat$z <- rowSums(abs(dat))`

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response @eipi10 Cheers,